# Count number of clients in a routine in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a database in mysql and php use to read the data, I have a table called payments where insert payments routines that make customers then are three tables "payments, routines and customers," Now the issue is that I want to load the number of customers using routine id "3", I got it resolved but a detail escapes me, I need the client ID is not the same on the counter and thus can not be counted twice for the same customer in a rut when you have two payments that routine.

The statement that I have is:

```
select r.name_routine, count(p.id_routine)
from payments p,routines r,customers c
where p.id_client=c.id_client
and p.id_routine=r.id_routine
and p.id_routine='3'
```

Data set, in spanish:

```
id_pago monto activo fecha_pago fecha_vencimiento observacion id_cliente id_rutina id_oferta 
     17   300      1 2016-02-24 2016-03-24        Ninguna             11         3      NULL
     13   450      1 2016-02-05 2016-07-05        Ninguna              8      NULL         8
     16   270      1 2016-02-05 2016-03-05        Ninguna              7         5      NULL
     11   490      1 2016-02-04 2016-04-04        Ninguna              8      NULL         5
     15   300      0 2016-02-04 2015-03-04        Ninguna             11         3      NULL
      9   330      1 2016-02-03 2016-03-03        Ninguna             11        10      NULL
     12   400      1 2016-02-03 2016-05-03        Ninguna             10      NULL         7
     10   500      1 2016-02-02 2016-06-02        Ninguna             10      NULL         4
     14   420      1 2016-02-02 2016-05-02        Ninguna              8      NULL         9
      5   250      0 2016-01-18 2016-02-18        Ninguna              5         7      NULL
      8   320      0 2016-01-05 2016-02-05        Ninguna              9         9      NULL
      7   250      0 2016-01-03 2016-02-03        Ninguna              7         7      NULL
      6   300      0 2016-01-02 2016-02-02        Ninguna              6         6      NULL
      2   520      1 2015-10-18 2016-03-18        Ninguna              2      NULL         2
      3   290      0 2015-10-18 2015-11-18        Ninguna              3         4      NULL
      4   550      0 2015-10-18 2016-01-18        Ninguna              4      NULL         3
```

In this table you can see that the routine "3" is used 2 times by the same customer (id_client 11), then my query should return the routine is used 1 time and not two, that's what I want to tell all clients that are in routine "3"

Try using distinct but returns the same result, how could you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT groupedTable.name_routine, COUNT(groupedTable.numbers) FROM
(
SELECT r.name_routine, count(p.id_routine) as numbers
FROM payments p,routines r,customers c
where p.id_client=c.id_client
and p.id_routine=r.id_routine
and p.id_routine='3'
GROUP BY p.id_client) as groupedTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Kordi.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select r.name_routine, count(distinct p.id_cliente) 
from payments p,routines r,customers c
where p.id_client=c.id_client
and p.id_routine=r.id_routine
and p.id_routine='3'
```